# Execute procedure each n minutes in Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

I want to make a query and then update a table using that data each period of time. Is it possible on Oracle and SQLServer?

Comment: Yes.  Though it is done differently on each.

Comment: It would be a much better idea to ask this separately for each of the two products. Not many of those who are well-versed in one product are as skilled in the other to be able to answer for both. Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can create a schedule job for this purpose. These links will be helpful for you.

For SQL Server -

[How to: Create a Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[How to: Schedule a Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

For Oracle - [Scheduler (DBMS_SCHEDULER)](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php)

Comment: I was using SQL Server Express, and I read somewhere it doesn't have the SQL Server Agent.
So for now I'm using Windows Task Scheduler to execute an script, and the same for oracle. For those using linux it's called cron.